# Unable to remove title/action bar when using notification drawer

Tags: java, android, titlebar

I am unable to remove the action/title bar from the activity when using the notification drawer. I've changed both the XML code and Java code to remove it.

```
 this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility
(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

 setContentView(R_layout_activity);

 getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Did you try to just disable the notification bar in your styles.xml?

Comment: yeah I tried it, doesn't work

Comment: Could you add your styles.xml and your application-XML-tag from the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Hey! I figured it out. Changed my app theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" in Manifest.xml. Thanks anyways!

Comment: That's what i asked you first :) Glad it worked!